# renv keeps telling that packages are not used while they are

Tags: r, dependencies, r-package, renv

I am using renv to make my project reproducible.

However, I have two packages needed that were not automatically taken in account when using `renv::snapshot()` (the `rnaturalearthdata` and `gifski` packages which are 2 dependencies of `rnaturalearth` and `knitr` packages I think).

Thus, I had to manually save them using `renv::record(<package>@<version>)`

**The problem is** now, when I use `renv::status()`, I have the following:

```
The following package(s) are no longer used in this project:
                    _
  gifski              [0.8.6]
  rnaturalearthdata   [0.1.0]

Use `renv::snapshot()` to remove them from the lockfile.
```

(which is normal because I don't call those packages directly in my project using `library()`, but they are automatically imported from their dependencies)

Is there a way to tell renv that it can consider them as necessary? Because the next time I use `renv::snapshot()` to add other packages, I don't want those 2 packages to be erased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that these are likely `Suggests` dependencies, and so are not automatically snapshotted by `renv` -- by default, it only includes "hard" dependencies; that is, packages which are part of `Imports`, `Depends` or `LinkingTo`.

The fix here is simple, though: create a file called `deps.R` with the contents:

```
library(gifski)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
```

to help instruct `renv` that these packages should be treated as hard dependencies.

See also the [FAQ](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/faq.html) for more details.

Comment: Thx @Kevin Ushey for this clear answer. I created the `deps.R` file at the root of my project. Then, I removed the packages from the `renv.lock` file as I put them manually in order to see if renv was taking into account the new `deps.R` file created. Unfortunaltely, it seems that I need to install them again manually. My question then is: why create an other file `deps.R` if I can write `library(<package>)` which seems to have the same result?

Comment: You can include the `library()` statements wherever you want; `deps.R` is just a convention. `renv` only includes packages which are installed in the project library in the lockfile, so if they're not showing up that implies they're either (1) not used or (2) not installed.